# What can I say about the function f here? (Uniform continuity)

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support, ie, the set of functions $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\exists$ $r>0$ such that $f(x) = 0$ when $|x|\geq r$. And any $f\in X$ is uniformly continuous.

Hint: $\frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(ny)^2}dy = 1$ (*) 
for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $\Lambda_n(f)(x) = \frac{n}{\sqrt(\pi)}\int_{\mathbb{R}}
f(x-y)e^{-(ny)^2}dy$

And I'm to prove that $\Lambda_n(f)$ is uniformly continuous
on $\mathbb{R}$ for all n.

So I'm thinking let $x,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, then

$|\Lambda(f)(x)-\Lambda(f)(x_2)| =
|\frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} [f(x-y)-f(x_2-y)]e^{-(ny)^2}dy|$

$=\epsilon|\frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-(ny)^2}dy|$, (for any $\epsilon>0$, bc f is uni cont, I'm almost certainly wrong about this step)

$= 1\cdot\epsilon$, by (*)

I'm very much lost and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon> 0$. Let $x, x_2\in \mathbb{R}$, then 
\begin{align}
|\Lambda_nf(x) - \Lambda_nf(x_2)| 
&= \left|\frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} [f(x-y)-f(x_2-y)]e^{-(ny)^2}dy\right|\\
&\leq  \frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x-y)-f(x_2-y)|e^{-(ny)^2}dy.
\end{align}
Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - x_2| < \delta$ implies $|f(x - y) - f(x_2 - y)| < \epsilon$. Hence, 
$$|\Lambda_nf(x) - \Lambda_nf(x_2)| < \epsilon \frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(ny)^2}dy = \epsilon$$
as long as $|x - x_2| < \delta$. This completes the proof. I'm not sure what your first paragraph about $X$ is for though.